# How to get rid of "+" in a line?

Tags: python, string

I have the txt file below and I want the remove the "+" if there is a + in front of the number.

> +905061459318
>
> +905458507534
>
> +905437335094

I have tried almost all of the solutions that exist in Stackoverflow but still, I cannot remove the + from the line.

The code is here.

```
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("numbers.txt")]
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("+"):
        line.replace("+","")
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: those phone numbers seem valid and currently used. If so, might be nasty to reveal them here.

Comment: Yeah. The 4th is mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `line.rstrip('\n')`. Make that `line.rstrip('\n').lstrip('+')`.